# application getting launched even if it is open android

Tags: android

In  my android application as soon as the user clicks on the application icon from menu the app is getting launched.It is happening even if the application is open earlier.

I would like to maintain the state like if the application is opened then the app should show the default opened page and should not launch it again.

Please let me know your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: this is bydefault in android that is home button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i solved this issue.Earlier i was using android:launchmode as single instance.When i removed this its working fine :)